# PHP Warning: touch() SAFE MODE Restriction in effect

Tags: php, function, configuration, web-hosting

I am facing this warning..

> PHP Warning:  touch() [function.touch]:
>   SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid is 507 is not
>   allowed to access ./cache/index.html owned by uid 99 in
>   /home/****/public_html/****/index.php on line 207............

How to fix it up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable the safe mode on your php.ini. Open your php.ini and search of "safe"

```
; Safe Mode
; http://php.net/safe-mode
safe_mode = Off
```

Set it to Off , save your file and restart your webserver.